CS 50 - Filter More Edges - all test cases passing (incl. 3x3) but not 4x4
I have written the below code for the Edges function for CS50. I pass all test cases except for the 4x4 image. I can't seem to figure out why my code would work for a 3x3 image but not a 4x4 (or an NxN). Perhaps I'm too close to the code so I'm hoping you all can help me.
I was thinking perhaps it might be because of how I'm detecting the edges but I dont see any reason why this would be different for 3x3 or NxN
// Detect edges
void edges(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{

    RGBTRIPLE copy[height][width];

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width ; j++)
        {
            copy[i][j] = image[i][j];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width ; j++)
        {
            edges_helper(height, width, i, j, image, copy);
        }
    }


    return;
}

void edges_helper(int height, int width, int current_row, int current_column, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width], RGBTRIPLE copy[height][width])
{
    // takes in my current position in the image and creates a 3x3 grid of the Red/Blue/Green value of the pixels around my position
    // it multiples that 3x3 grid by Gx and Gy, sums their squares, and sets current position Red/Blue/Green equal to that

    // create empty 3x3 grids for R, G, and B
    int red[3][3];
    int blue[3][3];
    int green[3][3];

    // populate Gx and Gy
    int gx[3][3] = {{-1,0,1},{-2,0,2},{-1,0,1}};
    int gy[3][3] = {{-1,-2,-1},{0,0,0},{1,2,1}};

    // populate red, blue, and green grids
    create_grids(current_row, current_column, height, width, red, blue, green, copy);

    int new_red = pow(matrix_multiply(3, 3, gx, red),2) + pow(matrix_multiply(3, 3, gy, red),2);
    int new_blue = pow(matrix_multiply(3, 3, gx, blue),2) + pow(matrix_multiply(3, 3, gy, blue),2);
    int new_green = pow(matrix_multiply(3, 3, gx, green),2) + pow(matrix_multiply(3, 3, gy, green),2);


    image[current_row][current_column].rgbtRed = minimum(round(sqrt(new_red)),255);
    image[current_row][current_column].rgbtBlue = minimum(round(sqrt(new_blue)),255);
    image[current_row][current_column].rgbtGreen = minimum(round(sqrt(new_green)),255);


   return;
}

// populate the 3x3 grids for Red, Blue, and Green that will then multiple against Gx and Gy
void create_grids(int current_row, int current_column, int height, int width, int red[height][width], int blue[height][width], int green[height][width], RGBTRIPLE copy[height][width])
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {

            if (current_row + i - 1 < 0 || current_row + i - 1 >= height || current_column + j - 1 < 0 || current_column + j - 1 >= width)
            {
                red[i][j] = 0;
                blue[i][j] = 0;
                green[i][j] = 0;
            }

            else
            {
                red[i][j] = copy[current_row+i-1][current_column+j-1].rgbtRed;
                blue[i][j] = copy[current_row+i-1][current_column+j-1].rgbtBlue;
                green[i][j] = copy[current_row+i-1][current_column+j-1].rgbtGreen;
            }
        }
    }
}

// multiple two matrices and return an integer value
int matrix_multiply(int height, int width, int x[height][width], int y[height][width])
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            sum += x[i][j] * y[i][j];
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

int minimum(int x, int y)
{
    return ((x<y) ? x : y);
}


Hint: don't use pow to square an integer.

...if you use pow() it would be better to have int new_red = (int)round(sqrt(pow(...) + pow(...))); etc and then apply minimum(new_red, 255).

You declared your function create_grids like this:
void create_grids(int current_row, int current_column, int height, int width, int red[height][width], int blue[height][width], int green[height][width], RGBTRIPLE copy[height][width])

This is wrong. The parameters height and width represent the size of the image (so the size of copy), but not the size of red, blue and green. These arrays always have a size of 3 times 3, irrespective of the size of the image.
That is why your program only works when the image size is 3 times 3. When the image has a size of 4 times 4, then you specified the wrong size for the parameters red, blue and green, so your program misbehaves.
In order to fix this, you can replace that line with the following:
void create_grids(int current_row, int current_column, int height, int width, int red[3][3], int blue[3][3], int green[3][3], RGBTRIPLE copy[height][width])

After doing that, your program will pass check50.
